# Python: Reading two csv files combining into a new cvs file , error: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to combine two datasets in python 2.7. They deal with different variables (windspd, winddir in one and co2 and h2o in the other) but match in date and time.

All of the data is originating in two csv files and I need it written to a new csv file but I keep getting the "error: too many values to unpack" at the third line.

I have double checked that I have the same number of variables as I have columns in my spreadsheet.

Any suggestions would be very helpful! Attached is my current code.

```
import numpy as np

winddir, windspd, month, day, year, hour, minute=np.loadtxt('E:\Wind05032014_08312015_flag_full.csv', delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str',skiprows=1)
co2m, h2om, day_1, month_1, year_1, hour_1, minute_1=np.loadtxt('E:\CO2_05032014_03182015_flag_full.csv', delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str',skiprows=1)

x=0
y=0

for eachdate in month:
    year_x=float(year[x])
    month_x=float(month[x])
    day_x=float(day[x])
    hour_x=float(hour[x])
    minute_x=float(minute[x])
    year_y=float(year_1[y])
    month_y=float(month_1[y])
    day_y=float(day_1[y])
    hour_y=float(hour_1[y])
    minute_y=float(minute_1[y])
    if (year_x == year_y) and (month_x==month_y) and (day_x==day_y) and (hour_x==hour_y) and (minute_x == minute_y):
        saveline=str(year_x)+','+str(month_x)+','+str(day_x)+','+str(hour_x)+','+str(minute_x)+','+winddir[x]+','+windspd[x]+','+co2m[y]+','+h2om[y]+'\n'
        savefile=open('E:\co2h2owind_05032014_03182015.csv', 'a')
        savefile.write(saveline)
        savefile.close()
        y+=1
    x+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `unpacking` error is the result of a mismatch between the number of variables on the left and the number of columns read by `loadtxt`.

You have 7 variables on the left.  We don't know how many columns there are in your file.

```
co2m, h2om, day_1, month_1, year_1, hour_1, minute_1 = 
    np.loadtxt('E:\CO2_05032014_03182015_flag_full.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True, dtype='str', skiprows=1)
```

I'd suggest first doing a

```
data = np.loadtxt('E:\CO2_05032014_03182015_flag_full.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='str', skiprows=1)
```

and then check the nature of `data`.

```
print(data.shape)
```

I was going to suggest you look at `data.dtype` as well, but have specified `str` as the type.  Are you sure you want that?  Just strings and no numbers?

Based on the error message I expect `data` will have more columns than 7.

`loadtxt` takes a `usecols` parameter if you want to a subset of the available columns.

You could also `unpack` columns from `data`:

```
 co2m, h2om, day_1, month_1, year_1, hour_1, minute_1 = data[:, :7]
```

I don't used the `unpack` option very often because it is easier to work with the 2d `data` array rather than all those variables.

If you used

```
data = np.loadtxt('E:\CO2_05032014_03182015_flag_full.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float, skiprows=1)
```

then `data` will be all floats and you wouldn't need to do the element by element conversion.

With `genfromtxt` you can specify `dtype=None` and it will load the array with a mix of strings and numbers, depending on what best fits the columns.  But that can produce a `structured array`, 1d with a compound `dtype`.  In that case you address columns by name, not index.  But that might be too advanced an issue.

================

A small example

dummy file:

```
In [135]: txt=b"""one, 1, 2
two, 3, 4
three, 5, 6"""
```

load as one array:

```
In [136]: data=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype='str')
In [137]: data
Out[137]: 
array([["b'one'", "b' 1'", "b' 2'"],
       ["b'two'", "b' 3'", "b' 4'"],
       ["b'three'", "b' 5'", "b' 6'"]], 
      dtype='<U8')

In [138]: data.shape
Out[138]: (3, 3)
```

Try unpack with 2 variables: (your error?)

```
In [139]: a,b=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str')
...
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Same with `usecols` and `float`:

```
In [140]: a,b=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype=float,usecols=[1,2])

In [141]: a
Out[141]: array([ 1.,  3.,  5.])

In [142]: b
Out[142]: array([ 2.,  4.,  6.])
```

load as structured array

```
In [148]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=None)

In [149]: data
Out[149]: 
array([(b'one', 1, 2), (b'two', 3, 4), (b'three', 5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])

In [150]: data['f1']         # access by field name
Out[150]: array([1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely try this. I think I did find an error in my spreadsheet and it had a blank column

Answer (score 0):

np.arrays are indexed by row first. So you are trying to fit all your rows into your column variables.
Try transposing first:

```
winddir, windspd, month, day, year, hour, minute=np.loadtxt('E:\Wind05032014_08312015_flag_full.csv', delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str',skiprows=1).T
```

Using checks like `print your_array.shape` could be useful...

Comment: I'm very new to python and I'm not sure I understand your question. I have both spreadsheets with the columns labeled in the first row and each has 1000's of rows of data. In the end I would like 1 spreadsheet with all of my variables matched according to date and time.

Comment: `a,b,c = my_array` is equivalent to `a = my_array[0]`, `b = my_array[1]` and `c = my_array[2]`. But `my_array[i]` is the i'th row, not the i'th column. So if you transpose your array first, using `my_array.T`, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Unfortunately I just made the correction that you originally suggested and I received the same error

Comment: @KateMcGowan so you are saving the csv from the spreadsheet. See if can just save a few rows of the spreadsheet to csv. there could be data errors in spreadsheet file.

Comment: Try to break down the line causing the error to isolate the problem: first `my_array = np.loadtxt(...)` then `print my_array.shape`. If you don't get `(n_rows,7)` then your spreadsheet is just not what you think and you have to check carefully the format of your data...

Comment: Thank you! I found an error in my spreadsheet and was able to get the correct dimensions using your method

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to find out where the problem is:

```
NUM_COLS = 7
rows = np.loadtxt(...)
print [x for x in rows if len(x) > NUM_COLS]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would use pandas, instead of numpy to read these csv's. Pandas has what seems to be more error checking. (And  for beginners, line up "=" signs it makes your code more readable.

Try this:

```
mydata=np.loadtxt('E:\CO2_05032014_03182015_flag_full.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str',skiprows=1)

print mydata.shape
```

The tuple return is (rows, columns)

```
savefile = open('E:\co2h2owind_05032014_03182015.csv', 'ab')  
for eachdate in month:
        year_x   =float(year[x])
        month_x  =float(month[x])
        day_x    =float(day[x])
        hour_x   =float(hour[x])
        minute_x =float(minute[x])

        year_y   =float(year_1[y])
        month_y  =float(month_1[y])
        day_y    =float(day_1[y])
        hour_y   =float(hour_1[y])
        minute_y =float(minute_1[y])

        if (year_x == year_y) and (month_x==month_y) and (day_x==day_y) and (hour_x==hour_y) and (minute_x == minute_y):

                 saveline = str(year_x)+','+str(month_x)+','+str(day_x)+','+str(hour_x)+','+str(minute_x)+','+winddir[x]+','+windspd[x]+','+co2m[y]+','+h2om[y]+'\n'
                 print saveline        
                 savefile.write(saveline)     
                 y+=1

            x+=1
            print x,y  
savefile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the print.shape and was able to get the correct dimensions after I fixed an error in my spreadsheet. However when I changed to this reformatted version the file that is created is blank.

Comment: ok, add a couple of print statements which later will be removed.. All we are doing is not opening and closing the file, repeatedly.